# transaction count for each card in last 1 day

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Please suggest how can we get  Count(card_num) where time between Tran_Datetime and Tran_Datetime_1daybefore for each card.
i need count for  each row of table(if no of rows are 10 then 10 counts).some cards no have multiple transactions in table and some are have only 1 transaction..and each card number have different date-time of transaction.

we can not use group by here as groupby will calculate 1 count for each card while we need separate count for each repeating card also.
any Logic in pandas(python) or SQL  is fine.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We are not a coding service. Please review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like what have you tried and where it went wrong.

Comment: I simply cannot figure out what you are trying to do.  What results do you want?

Comment: Question has nothing todo with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut  I think pandas is related to ML..I need to write this query in pandas for ML model..pls suggest..

Comment: A *whole bunch* of things are "related" to ML; if, say, you have issues setting up your GPU which you *will* use for ML modeling, you should certainly not tag such a question as `machine-learning`. Same logic applies here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume 'time' is a field. If not replace [time] with GETDATE() , if you want the current time to be the checker.

So simply:

> SELECT
>
> COUNT(*), card_num
>
> FROM WhateverYourTableIsCalled
>
> WHERE
> [time] BETWEEN Tran_Datetime AND Tran_Datetime1daybefore
>
> GROUP BY card_num

Comment: I already tried..Groupby will give only 1 count for all cards with multiple entries in table(same card no used to do transaction at different dates and time)..while i need separate count for each trandsaction as repeated card no will have separate counts becase transaction time is different ...Please check attached sample data..

Comment: No it won't... not if you don't include the transaction times in your select